# GWT: should we commit the symbolMap files?

Tags: git, gwt

I am tempted to exclude them from git, but I am really looking for advice here...

Same thing for *.nocache.js and the *.cache.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, anything that is produced by the build should be excluded from the SCM.

Assuming you're not using Maven or Gradle or other build tool with build output conventions (Maven puts everything in a `target/` folder, Gradle in a `build/` folder), then you should exclude (`.gitignore`) the whole folder that GWT creates within your `-war` directory, named after your module name or its `rename-to`; and basically any folder that GWT will create (e.g. if you pass `-extra` and/or `-deploy` to the compiler, or the `.gwt-unitCache`)
No need to deal with patterns like `*.symbolMaps`, `*.nocache.js`, `*.cache.js`, etc.

Comment: I am of with the WEB-INF/deploy, it really makes sense. What about the clean.css and the clean stuff? Is it always regenerated?

Comment: Yes, they come from the _clean_ theme (`<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean" />`)